# Value from buttonlistener class

Tags: java

Is there is a way that I can get a value from my buttonlistener class?

Is there is a way that I can set/store values into getPrice? That way I can call those values into a different class.

This is my Driver Class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pizza");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
       tp.addTab("Pizza", new PizzaPanel());




       frame.getContentPane().add(tp);
       frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
     } 
 }
```

PizzaClass

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class PizzaPanel extends JPanel
 {
    private JRadioButton pep,com,pine,meat;
    public PizzaPanel()
    {

        JRadioButton th = new JRadioButton();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       //ButtonListener gen = new ButtonListener();
        General gen1 = new General();
        Total tol = new Total();


        //add(gen,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(gen1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(tol, BorderLayout.EAST);



    }


}
```

General Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.*;

public class General extends JPanel
{
    private static JRadioButton pep;
    private static JRadioButton pine;
    private static JRadioButton meat;
    private static JRadioButton com;
    private static JLabel cool, label;
    private static double money;
    private static double prices, total;
    double pepAmount = 0;
    private static Action e;

    public General()
    {

       cool = new JLabel("What type of pizza would you like?");

       label = new JLabel("Total "+money);
       pep = new JRadioButton("Pepperoni");
       pine = new JRadioButton("Pineapple");
       meat = new JRadioButton("Meat Lovers");
       com = new JRadioButton("Combination");


       ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
       group.add(pep);
       group.add(pine);
       group.add(meat);
       group.add(com);

    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    pep.addActionListener(listener);
    pine.addActionListener(listener);
    com.addActionListener(listener);
    meat.addActionListener(listener);
    //Total tol = new Total();


    add(cool);
    add(pep);
    add(pine);
    add(com);
    add(meat);
    add(label);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 700));
    setBackground(Color.white);

}

public static void setPrice(double price)
{
    money = price;

}

public static  double getPrice()
{
    return money;
}






public static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{




    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {  
        if(e.getSource() == pep)
        {

         setPrice(14);
         label.setText("Pepperoni Cost $" +getPrice());

        }

        if(e.getSource() == pine)
        {
            money = 16;
        setPrice(16);
        label.setText("Pineapple Cost $" +getPrice());

        }

        if(e.getSource() == com)
        {
            money=18 ;
        setPrice(18);
        label.setText(" Cost $" +getPrice());

        }

        if(e.getSource() == meat)
        { 
            money = 20;
        setPrice(20);
        label.setText(" Cost $" +getPrice());
        }


    }



}   

}
```

Total Class

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Total extends JPanel
{
   JRadioButton pep;
   JRadioButton pine = null;
   JRadioButton meat = null;
   JRadioButton com = null;
   JLabel col;

   public Total()
   {


    JLabel p = new JLabel();
    double gen = General.getPrice();
    col = new  JLabel("Total"+ General.getPrice());
    System.out.println(gen+" "+General.getPrice());
    //pep = new JRadioButton("this");


    add(col);
     //add(pep);


 }



}
```

Comment: Please don't post your entire project's code here. We only need to see the relevant code.

Comment: Read about decorator pattern and decorate your pizza with ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

I'll skip over the reasons why you don't need (and probably shouldn't use) `static` for most of your classes and variables since you are new to Java, but you can do something like the following.

I think the reason why you wanted `getPrice` to be `static` is so you could use it in `Total`? If so, you can pass a `General` parameter to `Total` also.

**ButtonListener**

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    private General g;

    public ButtonListener(General g) {
      this.g = g;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {  
        if(e.getSource() == pep) {
            g.setPrice(14);
            label.setText("Pepperoni Cost $" +getPrice());
        }

        // other if's (though should be "else if ()")
    }
}
```

**General**

```
public class General extends JPanel
{
    private JRadioButton pep;
    private JRadioButton pine;
    private JRadioButton meat;
    private JRadioButton com;
    private JLabel cool, label;
    private double money;
    private double prices, total;
    double pepAmount = 0;

    public General() {
        // other stuff

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(this);
        pep.addActionListener(listener);
        // other addActionListener

        //Total tol = new Total();

        // other stuff
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        money = price;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return money;
    }

}
```